# SP.RelatedItemManager.getRelatedItems return 0 items

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have customized TaskList of the SharePoint 2016.

In the Editor mode under JS-Link options i found this:
"SP.UI.RelatedItems.js | ~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/FinTemplates/RelatedItems.js"

RelatedItems.js:

```
NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("SP.UI.RelatedItems.js");
//SP.SOD.notifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("SP.UI.RelatedItems.js");

(function () { 

function registerRenderer()
{
    var filedContext = {};
    filedContext.Templates = {};
    filedContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "LinkTitle": {
            "View": titleViewTemplate
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(filedContext);
}
function titleViewTemplate(ctx) {

    var title = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;              
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var relItems = SP.RelatedItemManager.getRelatedItems(context, ctx.listName, ctx.CurrentItem.ID);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            //return relItems[0].$2_1;
            $('a').filter(function (index) {return $(this).text() === title }).attr('href', relItems[0].$2_1);
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        }
    );

    return '<a>' + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + '</a>'
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');
//ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'SP.UI.RelatedItems.js');
 })();
```

After refreshing page under google chrome console, folowing error throws:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$2_1' of undefined*

A lot of troubleshooting pointing me to this code block:

```
  var relItems = SP.RelatedItemManager.getRelatedItems(context, ctx.listName, ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
```

**relItems** gets 0 items!
variable such **context**, **ctx.listName**, **ctx.CurrentItem.ID** have a right values.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am just looking on your code for long ,should it not be `var relItems = SP.RelatedItemManager.getRelatedItems(ctx, ctx.listName, ctx.CurrentItem.ID);`? Pay attention first parameter is ctx ,you did context

Comment: I have already use this version. But throw issue: 

TypeError: a.addQuery is not a functionTypeError: a.addQuery is not a functionTypeError: a.addQuery is not a functionTypeError: ...